# Prove der (A) is closed

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to prove that if for each $x \in \text{cl}(A)$ we have that $\{x\}$ is closed then $\text{der}(\text{der}(A)) \subseteq \text{der}(A)$.
In other words, the derivated set is closed

$\text{cl}(A)$ denotes the closure of $A$ and $\text{der(A)}$ denotes the derived set of $A$, i.e., $\text{der}(A)=\{x \in X\mid x \ \text{is an accumulation point of} \ A \} $

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use proper formatting and clarify your post.

Comment: I'm guessing the derived set?

Comment: And what is a derived set?

Comment: Der I say, what is der?

Comment: Yes, with der(A) i mean the derivated set

Comment: You mean *derived set*, not derivated. I.e. the set of limit points of $A$.